# Why this class assignment is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I've wrote this peice of code, this works fine in FF and Chrome but not in IE. Why is it?

```
<html>
    <header>
        <style type="text/css">
            .red{
                color: red;
            }
            .green{
                color: green;
            }
            .yellow{
                color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv" style="height: 50px">Some contents</div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="change" onclick="onClick(this)">Red</input> 
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="change" onclick="onClick(this)">Green</input> 
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="change" onclick="onClick(this)">Yellow</input> 
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onClick(el){
                var className = "";
                if(el.value == 1){
                    className = "red";
                }else if(el.value == 2){
                    className = "green";
                }else if(el.value == 3){
                    className = "yellow";
                }

                document.getElementById("mydiv").setAttribute("class", className);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE does not support the setAttribute method for class attribute.

You can solve this issue by using `document.getElementById("mydiv").className = className;` instead of `document.getElementById("mydiv").setAttribute("class", className);`.

But I think if you use a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can forget about these kind of browser compatibility issues.

```
<html>
    <header>
        <style type="text/css">
            .red{
                color: red;
            }
            .green{
                color: green;
            }
            .yellow{
                color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="mydiv" style="height: 50px">Some contents</div>
        <div id="ctrls">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="change" divClass="red">Red</input> 
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="change" divClass="green">Green</input> 
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="change" divClass="yellow">Yellow</input> 
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var mydiv = $("#mydiv");
                var myctrls = $("#ctrls").delegate("input[name='change']", "click", function(e){
                    var el = $(e.currentTarget);
                    mydiv.removeClass(mydiv.attr("class")).addClass(el.attr("divClass"));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or maybe even .className += " "+className;  ?

Comment: @Danjah but then we have to remove the already assigned class in this case. So we need to get all the assigned classes then remove the previous class then add current class.

Comment: For what it's worth, IE kind of does support setAttribute. [You have to tell it to setAttribute('className') instead of setAttribute('class').](http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/article/1394/the-browser-dom-and-the-class-attribute)

Answer (score 4):

Arun's correct about the solution being `.className` instead.  On top of that, I'd simplify things quite a bit with an object map, like this:

```
var classMap = { "1":"red", "2":"green", "3":"yellow" };
function onClick(el){
  document.getElementById("mydiv").className = classMap[el.value];
}
```

Comment: I think this is a better idea. I'll update my jquery solution based on this

Comment: Sorry,  I thought the jquery solution was a different one. An completely different one. I'll revert my answer